# Subtract n months from a date field in hive

Tags: datetime, hive

I am trying to limit a table by a specific number of months, 24 for example in my WHERE clause. I have used the following with no success:

Where month(EVENT_START_DT_TM) > add_months(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),-1)

EVENT_START_DT_TM is a true datetime field and I want to have a 24 month look back period from the current date matching up against that field. Looking at the HIVE manual, a lot of date functions require date STRINGS, but what a true DATE field?

Answer (score 1):

use **Current_date()** and **add_months()** function to get date before 24 months then use **date_format()** function to change the format as per your needs(matches to **EVENT_START_DT_TM** 
 field format)

```
hive> select date_format(add_months(current_date(),-24),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
+--------------------------+--+
|           _c0            |
+--------------------------+--+
| 2016-06-29 00:00:00.000  |
+--------------------------+--+
```

True date field is when your data in date field matches with **yyyy-MM-dd** format then you can extract months from the field

```
hive> select month("2018-10-12");
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 10   |
+------+--+
```

if field values are not true date field i.e not in yyyy-MM-dd format

```
 hive> select month("20181012");
+-------+--+
|  _c0  |
+-------+--+
| NULL  |
+-------+--+
```

we cannot extract month directly by using months function instead we need to change the format of the field then extract the month by using from_unixtime/unix_timestamp..etc functions (or) using substring functions